# Which one is right, "The text to search for must be typed in the ..." or "The text to be searched must be typed in the ..."?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, word-usage

Which one is right,

- "The text *to search* must be typed in the ..." or
- "The text *to search for* must be typed in the ..." or
- "The text *to be searched* must be typed in the ..." or
- "The text *to be searched for* must be typed in the ..."

Also, what is the topic in English grammar for such a sentence form?

Comment: The topics you might want to look into are **infinitive forms** and **prepositional phrases**.

Comment: @Waterbagel, thank you very much. Can your comment be vote up?

Comment: You can, but only if you have at least 15 reputation on this site. You'll get there soon enough. :)

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, all four options that you provide in your question are correct. But those options fall into two distinct categories. One category consists of phrases describing the words that the search engine will search for in other text:

> The text to search for must be typed in the ...

and

> The text to be searched for must be typed in the ...

The other category consists of phrases describing the text that will be searched by the search engine (presumably for specific words not identified here that are contained in that text):

> The text to search must be typed in the ..."

and

> The text to be searched must be typed in the ...

Realistically, you almost certainly want to talk about the first category of phrases—search terms that the search engine is to look for in a much larger universe of text, rather than the entire universe of text that the search engine is to search across—since the amount of typing involved in the second category quickly becomes intolerable.